# Zookeeper cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-zookeeper, bigdata

I am trying to setup a zookeeper cluster on 3 AWS ec2 machines, but continuously getting same error:

```
2016-10-19 16:30:23,177 [myid:2] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumCnxManager@382] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address /xxx.31.34.102:3888
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:840)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:762)
2016-10-19 16:30:23,185 [myid:2] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=2]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:FastLeaderElection@849] - Notification time out: 60000
```

1) I have same security group for all three machines.
2) Using private ips of machine in conf

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
dataDir=/opt/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the 
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeIinterval=1
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=x.31.34.105:2888:3888
server.3=x.31.34.102:2888:3888
```

3) Even tested with actual private ip of own machine instead of "0.0.0.0".

Not been able to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you find a way out? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

For each node you must make sure that you have specified 0.0.0.0 as the node's ip address.

i.e.: For server 01

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.10.10:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.2.1:2888:3888
```

For server 02

```
server.1=192.168.x.x:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.2.1:2888:3888
```

For server

```
server.1=192.168.x.x:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.10.10:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. If you use privateDNS of the EC2 instances you don't need to specify 0.0.0.0 as the node's ip address.