# zookeeper cluster setup on AWS issue: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup zookeeper cluster on AWS and while running zookeeper I am getting following error:

```
[2017-03-22 11:32:25,038] INFO Notification time out: 1600 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2017-03-22 11:32:31,644] WARN Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /<IP2>:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:840)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:762)
```

Any idea how to fix it ??

My zookeeper.properties are like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
#clientPort=2181
clientPort=2080
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0

server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=<IP2>:2888:3888

#add here more servers if you want
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
tickTime=2000
```

My guess: I think there is some networking issue. But I don't know what to do?

Comment: I found similar question on stackoverflow [Duplicate question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137077/zookeeper-cluster-on-aws/40810413#40810413)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zookeeper cluster on AWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137077/zookeeper-cluster-on-aws)